# What is the reason for the stone giant's 15' reach with the greatclub?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, weapons, reach

The standard stone giant stat block has a reach of 15' with its greatclub melee attack. However, I can see no reason from the rules or description for it to be so, instead of the standard 10' reach of all other huge giants' melee weapon attacks. Is there a rules-based explanation for this longer-than-usual reach?

Comment: This is opinion based/designer reasons. Voting to close.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I've already checked previous editions, this exception didn't exist in any of them, not aware of any newer lore that would explain it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about designer intent.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov to state that this is about opinion or designer intent presumes the answer is that there is no rules- or lore-based explanation in the official texts. If there IS such an explanation, then the question is not about opinion or designer intent.

Comment: @Rykara to state that this is about opinion or designer intent presumes the answer is that there is no rules- or lore-based explanation in the official texts. If there IS such an explanation, then the question is not about opinion or designer intent.

Comment: @ErïchJacoby-Hawkins See this meta discussion for more details: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7968/62294

Comment: @ThomasMarkov thanks but that doesn't seem to help. I am trying to figure out if this particular example which seems to contradict the rule without any given reason actually has some reason I have missed for which it contradicts the general rules. It is not at all clear that the designers intended to contradict the rule, so perhaps there is a rule or pattern that I have missed which explains it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I also don't see that it's about opinion. 5e is full of specific rules that contradict a general rule, but usually they are stated as such. It is not an opinion that this particular stat is an exception - it is a fact that it contradicts the general weapons rules AND the clear pattern for monsters. So I am trying to find out if there is any indication that some other rule (or lore-based exception) is at play. 5e doesn't contradict itself randomly or arbitrarily; the monster stat blocks are built using clear and discernable patterns.

Comment: @ErïchJacoby-Hawkins There’s no rule that’s “all giants have 10 foot reach”. You’ve observed a pattern, and are asking if the game designers intentionally broke that pattern for this case, which is off topic.

Comment: “5e doesn’t contradict itself randomly or arbitrarily” - You must be new here.

Comment: Anyway, moving forward, I recommend opening a discussion on meta if you think your question is not off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is an error because none of the usual reasons for extended reach apply.
The standard greatclub does not have the reach property.

The stone giant description says nothing about long reach (unlike, say, the long-limbed trait of a bugbear) or an oversized (longer) stone club. It does talk about the stone giant's special skill with throwing rocks, although in game mechanics this only applies to catching them, not throwing them.

The stone giant is shorter than the frost, cloud, and storm giants, all of whom have 10' reach with their melee weapons (greataxe, morningstar, and greatsword). The cyclops, which is also huge and has 1 HD more than the stone giant (thus is of comparable size) has a 10' reach with the greatclub, as does the hill giant who also uses a greatclub. And the fire giant's greatsword is 10' reach.

The oversized weapon trait is dealt with by the increased damage dice. Simply being a larger version of the weapon does not grant extra reach in 5e; all huge giants have a 10' reach with whatever oversized melee weapon they use (1- or 2-handed) which apparently comes from their huge size. (Large giants, like ogres or trolls, do not have 10' reach. The large Oni has a 10' reach because it uses a glaive, which has the reach property.)

Nothing in AD&D, 2e, 3/3.5e or 4e mentioned stone giants having longer than normal reach with a club or other melee weapon, so it's not part of traditional D&D giant lore. In AD&D, different giants had different ranges for throwing rocks, but in 5e they all have 60/240 and they all (stone giants included) have their attack bonus based on their strength and standard proficiency.

Comment: I reviewed *Volo's Guide to Monsters* and didn't find anything in there either.